# Copying a file on Windows 8 gives "not enough memory" even with plenty of memory and disk space

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, file-transfer, macrium

I had this problem when copying a large (50GB) disk image file ([Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx)) from my Flash Drive to my computer.

"Out of Memory.  There is not enough memory to complete this operation."
  [image: Out of Memory Error Dialog]

I had more than double the disk space, had about 12GB of RAM so the error message didn't make much sense to me.  But this was largest file I could remember copying so thought the size might have something to do with it.

Comment: Hi Nathan. I made a few adjustments to your posts to make them even better. If you feel my edits changed your intent, feel free to roll back, or even better simply [edit] further.

Comment: First question is what is the file system, NTFS? (if it's fat32, then it won't accept due to file size limitation) - next question is if it's defragmented such that a 50gb file can fit in a single spot.

Answer (score 24):

I downloaded [Teracopy](https://codesector.com/teracopy) and tried using that to copy the file; it too failed but gave me a much better file error message: "Open Error: Access is denied"

I check the file Security Permissions (right click Properties --> Security) and indeed the current user did not have Read Access.  I add the permissions and it copied fine.

I am guessing because the file was created from a Boot Disk perhaps it didn't know which user to assign the proper NTFS permissions to (although I think it could just leave it open to everyone?)

Also I think Windows 8.1 has a bug when it tries copying a file with wrong file permissions it falls through and displays the wrong error message.

Comment: I was going to say "Check your filesystem to see if you have FAT32", but I guess I would have failed a lot. I would never think about permissions. Nice catch!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - It wouldn't have made sense to even mention FAT32 due to the size of the file which based on the description would have been 6GB.

Comment: @Ramhound It actually would make sense. If you format a 32GB pen drive with FAT32 and try to copy a file that takes 4GB or more, it will say that you don't have enough space, even if you have 20GB free.

Comment: Alright;  I see your line of thought;  Yes indeed.

Comment: Does Windows still have that annoying property that all file copies have to go through the boot partition? I remember (years ago) that trying to copy a file from a CD-ROM to my D: partition would fail if I didn't have enough space on C: for the temp file.

Comment: @TMN: Did dinosaurs roam the earth at the time, too?

Comment: @TMN: No, I don't believe so. At least as far back as XP I recall copying files that were _almost_ certainly larger than the amount of free space I had on my boot partition at the time.

Comment: @Nathan: Lol @ Windows 8.1. This is kind of funny. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen today while copying files off a SATA drive connected to a USB3 dock via an adaptor. When I went to check the drive for permissions (as per Nathan's answer) I found that the drives had vanished.  I unplugged and replugged the hard drive and it worked fine afterwards.